# I think my book's solution to this symmetric matrices problem is wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working on a problem in my book that asks us to say whether the matrix on the left in the link below is symmetric, and I think my book's answer is wrong. Can anyone confirm?

http://calcchat.com/book/Elementary-Linear-Algebra-7e/7/3/3/

I know that the matrix isn't symmetric, but the transpose of the matrix on the left DOES equal the matrix on the right, even though they have a "does not equal sign"...right?

Comment: The matrix does not equal its transpose.  Which is exactly what is shown in your link.

Comment: this matrix ,say A, is not symmetric because $A^t\not = A$. Actually we have $a_{12}=2\not = a_{21}=3 $. so yes there is a little mistake in your book.

Comment: @DougM But the matrix on the left transposed does equal the matrix on the right. That equation doesn't have anything to do with whether the original matrix equals its transpose.

Comment: I see what you are saying, there should not be the superscript T.  By the way, most high level math books are riddled with errors.  I had one class where we were using a book written by another prof in the class, and we were kept a notebook of errata to deliver to the author at end of term.  And this was about 15 years after the book was originally printed.